# Java Clips Lag on First Play

Tags: java, audio, lag

I have sound effects for a game. Upon the game frame opening, the first sound lags behind. After that sound plays, no more lag is experienced.
Here's my clip player:

```
public enum SoundEffect
{
    WALL("ping_pong_8bit_plop"),
    PADDLE("ping_pong_8bit_beeep"),
    POINT("ping_pong_8bit_peeeeeep");
    public static enum Volume
    {
        MUTE, UNMUTE
    }
    public static Volume volume = Volume.MUTE;
    private Clip clip;
    SoundEffect (String file)
    {
        try
        {
            AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource(file+".wav"));
            AudioFormat format = inputStream.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
            clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(inputStream);

        }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException uae)
        {
            uae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (LineUnavailableException lue)
        {
            lue.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
    public void play()
    {
        if (volume != Volume.MUTE)
        {
            if (clip.isRunning())
                clip.stop();
            clip.flush();
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();
        }
    }
    static void init()
    {
        values();
    } 
}
```

So when I call SoundEffect.WALL.play() for example, it plays fine overall, but the very first time it plays there is a huge lag spike. What can I do to solve this, preferably still using Clips?

Comment: *"What can I do to solve this"* - Pre-load the clip prior to wanting to play it...

Comment: Do you mean just using my init method? I did do that, but do you mean there’s something else I should do to pre-load my clips?

Comment: I'd use something like `SoundEffect.WALL` and set the `framePosition` to the last and then the first position to force the loading of the stream BEFORE you need to use it - so yes, do it in your init method

Comment: Okay, so I've been trying `SoundEffect.WALL.clip.setFramePosition(SoundEffect.WALL.clip.getFrameLength());`
  `SoundEffect.WALL.clip.start();`
  `SoundEffect.WALL.clip.setFramePosition(0);` with no luck. The sound effect is preloaded successfully, but the preloading is still audible when I try this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same bug, the first play of a clip was about 1-2 sec delayed, no matter when the play()-method is called. What I did is I played a clip in the main() method which is a half seccond long and contains nothing (no sound). This means that the play() method of the actual sound isn't called the first time, and for me, it works. Hope it helped.

Comment: I know that it's just avoiding the bug and not fixing it, but it seems like, there's no solution yet on any website, so probably that's the way to go right now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate Thread

```
Thread music = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() { your code }
};
music.start();
```

Comment: Try loading it before you need to use it, it probably takes time to load. Also the computers processing speed could play a role